# Azure Storage with CMK, Key Rotation reminder by email

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-storage-account

We are planning to use Customer-Managed Keys (CMK) for our GPv2 Storage Account. The key rotation schedule that we are planning to implement is 1 year.

Is there anyway that I can set a reminder, so that Azure sends out an email or notification to an email address (Group Mailbox or DL) just say few days (10 days) before the expiry of the key, so that action can be taken in rotating the CMK?

Appreciate any reply

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be a [Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/aa) with EventGrid trigger. There is a [Microsoft.KeyVault.KeyNearExpiry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#available-event-types) event that will be generated by your key vault 30 days before a key expires.

[image]

Comment: You have mentioned about using the Event Grid Key Vault Near Expiry Event. So i would like to know how will Key Vault talk to Event Grid, do i need to configure a topic or Event Hub from the Events menu in the Key Vault or i start directly from Logic App Designer and configure it there?

Comment: What kind of role needs to be given to the System Assigned Managed Identity of Logic App to the Key Vault? Will key vault reader role suffice to read the expiration dates of the keys?